# Why are my SLURM tasks allocated to two nodes at the same time?

Tags: mpi, slurm

I have 4 independent tasks that require 16 cores each (because each task calls `mpirun -n 16`), and each of my nodes has 32 cores. I would like to run the 4 tasks in parallel with the same sbatch submission, but slurm is only running 2 in parallel.

With this (simplified) sbatch file:

```
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --ntasks 2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 16
export SRUN_CPUS_PER_TASK=16

mpirunjob1 &
mpirunjob2 &
mpirunjob3 &
mpirunjob4 &

wait
```

I expected SLURM to allocate 16 of the 64 total cores I'm requesting to each task. However, that's not happening. Using `sacct` I get:

```
                                        51434902.0                 pmi_proxy   node[582-583]   00:00:36  COMPLETED        00:19:12                   cpu=32,mem=125G,node=2
                                        51434902.1                 pmi_proxy   node[582-583]   00:00:36  COMPLETED        00:19:12                   cpu=32,mem=125G,node=2
                                        51434902.2                 pmi_proxy   node[582-583]   00:00:36  COMPLETED        00:19:12                   cpu=32,mem=125G,node=2
                                        51434902.3                 pmi_proxy   node[582-583]   00:00:35  COMPLETED        00:18:40                   cpu=32,mem=125G,node=2
```

which suggests that each of the 4 tasks was allocated 32 cores and 2 nodes. The consequence of this is that it first runs 2 tasks and then when they are finished the other 2 tasks run. Inspecting the nodes while it is running (with `top` and `1`) I can see that half of each node is just sleeping (because the each task is only really using 16 cores instead of the 32 that slurm is allocating for unknown reasons).

If instead I run with just two tasks, then everything works fine, all CPUs of 1 node are working and the two tasks are completed in parallel. Issue seems to appear when the requested amount of CPUs require more than 1 node.

What am I doing wrong? Why is SLURM giving 32 cores per task if I am telling it to give only 16 cores?

Comment: generally speaking, `mpirun` jobs do not know each other, so they are likely to end using the same cores. your best option is probably to use direct run (aka `srun ... &`) and let SLURM do the cpu binding. you will need some support for `srun` from your MPI library though.